# Stripe charge issue with stripe payment

Tags: php, html, stripe-payments

What I'm doing is simple, using stripes JS code to charge a customer, like so.

```php
<form method="post" action="?p=charge">
    <script 
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
        class="stripe-button" 
        data-key="pk_test_ngaGkIg8PowWzIh5GRS18tRO" 
        data-image="img/logo.png" 
        data-name="Wine Glass Transport" 
        data-description="Transport Case (65.00/each + Shipping)" 
        data-amount="<?php echo $FinalTotal * 100; ?>" > 
    </script>
<input type="hidden" name="final" value="<?php echo $FinalTotal * 100; ?>" />
</form>
```

From there it gets sent to the charge script like so.

```php
<?php

require_once('inc/stripe/lib/Stripe.php');
try {

    var_dump($_POST);
    Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_");
    $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
        "amount" => $_POST['final'] / 100,
        "currency" => "usd",
        "card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
        "description" => "Wine Glass Transport Case"
    ));

    echo '<h1>Your payment has been completed. Thank You,<br><br>Click <a href="https://www.wineglasstransport.com/index.php">Here</a></h1>';

    //users email.
    echo $_POST['stripeEmail'];
} catch (Stripe_CardError $e) {
    echo 'There was an error with your card!<br><br>';
    echo $e;
}

//catch the errors in any way you like

catch (Stripe_InvalidRequestError $e) {
    echo 'We can not process your order there was something wrong with the information submitted, please go back and correct this error,if the error persists please contact the administrator<br><br>';
    echo $e;
    // Invalid parameters were supplied to stripe's API

} catch (Stripe_AuthenticationError $e) {
    echo 'Sorry, we can not connect to stripe, please contact Administrator.';
    // Authentication with stripe's API failed
    // (maybe you changed API keys recently)

} catch (Stripe_ApiConnectionError $e) {
    // Network communication with stripe failed
    echo 'sorry we cant connect to stripe please contact website administrator.';
} catch (Stripe_Error $e) {
    // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
    // yourself an email
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'UH OH, something Really went wrong here, Contact the system administrator ASAP!';
    // Something else happened, completely unrelated to stripe
}
```

at this point, I have no clue what is going on and I'm getting this error

> exception 'Stripe_InvalidRequestError' with message 'Unrecognized
>   request URL (POST: /v1/stripecharges). Please see
>   https://stripe.com/docs or we can help at
>   https://support.stripe.com/.' in
>   /home/arthmael/PhpstormProjects/Vino/inc/stripe/lib/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php:147
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/arthmael/PhpstormProjects/Vino/inc/stripe/lib/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php(268):
>   Stripe_ApiRequestor->handleApiError('{\n "error": {\n...', 404, Array)
>
> ## 1 /home/arthmael/PhpstormProjects/Vino/inc/stripe/lib/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php(109):
>
> Stripe_ApiRequestor->_interpretResponse('{\n "error": {\n...', 404) #2
>   /home/arthmael/PhpstormProjects/Vino/inc/stripe/lib/Stripe/ApiResource.php(143):
>   Stripe_ApiRequestor->request('post', '/v1/stripecharg...', Array,
>   Array) #3
>   /home/arthmael/PhpstormProjects/Vino/inc/stripe/lib/Stripe/Charge.php(38):
>   Stripe_ApiResource::_scopedCreate('Stripe_Charge', Array, NULL) #4
>   /home/arthmael/PhpstormProjects/Vino/pages/charge.php(21):
>   Stripe_Charge::create(Array) #5
>   /home/arthmael/PhpstormProjects/Vino/inc/content.php(6):
>   include('/home/arthmael/...') #6
>   /home/arthmael/PhpstormProjects/Vino/index.php(6):
>   include('/home/arthmael/...') #7 {main}

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I realized after jumping on the stripe irc, that I was using an outdated API, so I updated to that and here is my code now:

Comment: Can you print_r($charge) please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found 3 problems in my code.

1. I am using an outdated API :P
2. my hidden input for the amount was not being posted because it was after the embedded script. like this...

```php
<form action="?p=charge" method="post">
    <script 
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
        class="stripe-button" 
        data-key="pk_test_ngaGkIg8PowWzIh5GRS18tRO" 
        data-amount="<?php echo $FinalTotal * 100; ?>" 
        data-name="Wine Glass Transport" 
        data-description="Transport Case (65.00/each + Shipping)" 
        data-image="img/logo.png">
    </script>
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $FinalTotal; ?>">
</form>
```

so I just switched it up

```php
<form action="?p=charge" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $FinalTotal; ?>">
    <script 
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
        class="stripe-button" 
        data-key="pk_test_ngaGkIg8PowWzIh5GRS18tRO" 
        data-amount="<?php echo $FinalTotal * 100; ?>" 
        data-name="Wine Glass Transport" 
        data-description="Transport Case (65.00/each + Shipping)" 
        data-image="img/logo.png">
    </script>
</form>
```

3. I also did not have the `$_POST['stripeToken']` variable on my charge.php page.

thanks for the help though guys!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the array.

Try this:

```
 $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(
  "amount" => $_POST['final']/100,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
  "description" => "Wine Glass Transport Case"
);
```